# collections.js - differance between SortedMap and SortedArrayMap

Tags: javascript, collectionsjs

I was searching for a sorted map in javascript and found collections.js's implementation - `SortedMap`. I also see that they have something called `SortedArrayMap`.

In the description of `SortedArrayMap` it says:

> A map of key value pairs, sorted by key, **backed by an array**.

([Source](https://www.collectionsjs.com/sorted-array-map))

And in the description of `SortedMap` it says:

> A map with entries sorted by key.

What exactly does **backed by an array** mean? and what is the difference between it and the normal `SortedMap`?

Comment: [Sorted Array Map](https://www.collectionsjs.com/sorted-array-map)
[Sorted Map](https://www.collectionsjs.com/sorted-map)

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, `SortedArrayMap` uses a binary search strategy to maintain the order of the entries and is backed by an array, which means that use an array as a basic data structure(to maintain data of key). So that means in the end, that it uses a map based on `SortedArray` class.

However, `SortedMap` is a general `key/value` collection, where you can access values with their relative key(quick access rather than an array order).

Anyway, if you want to dive a bit more into this topic, you can find a very good explanation on the is the official website of [collections.js](https://www.collectionsjs.com/),

Answer (score 1):

As stated on http://www.collectionsjs.com/map, maps are different as they work like dictionaries but accepting even objects as a key.

Reading the Dict documentation on http://www.collectionsjs.com/dict we understand that:

> A dictionary is a specialized map. The keys are required to be strings.

An array is simply a data structure where you can insert anything using a simple `push(thingToInsert)`. Items inserted into an Array are just values without a key to point to them.